# get data from dynamic form into javascript and returning it callculated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

i have form that dynamically add data..   the data is about products name, how much product and prices with or without taxes..

the form adds inputes :

this is originally form: (after the dynamically generation:

```
<div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
<div class="input_fields_wrap" class="float-left" dir="rtl" align="right" width="900px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button class="add_field_button">הוסף עוד שורה</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</br>
    <div align="center"> שם המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="text" id="item_name[]" name="item_name[]" />
    &nbsp;כמות המוצר :<input type="number" id="how_much[]"   name="how_much[]" style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;"  />
    &nbsp;עלות המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="number" id="item_price0]" name="item_price[]" onchange="update1(0);" style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;" />
    עלות אחרי מע&quot;מ&nbsp; :<input type="number"  id="item_price_tax[]" name="item_price_tax[0]" onchange="update2(0);" style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;" />
    סכום&nbsp; :<input type="number"  id="item_price_total[]" name="item_price_total[]" onchange="update1(0);"  style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 125px;"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp;   &nbsp;
   </div>
```

here is the dynamical outo generation :

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 99999; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
                   $(wrapper).append('<div class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;"  align="center">שם המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="text" id="item_name['+x+']" name="item_name['+x+']" />&nbsp;כמות המוצר :<input type="number" id="how_much['+x+']" name="how_much['+x+']"  style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;"  onchange="update1('+x+');"  />&nbsp;עלות המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="number" id="item_price['+x+']"  style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;" name="item_price['+x+']" onchange="update1('+x+');"  /> עלות אחרי מע&quot;מ&nbsp; :<input type="number"  id="item_price_tax['+x+']" style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;" name="item_price_tax['+x+']" onchange="update1('+x+');" />סכום&nbsp; :<input type="number" style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 125px;"  id="item_price_total['+x+']" name="item_price_total['+x+']" onchange="update1('+x+');" /><a href="#" class="remove_field">הסר</a></div>'); //add input box
          }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

</SCRIPT>
```

now i want to make script that fill in the last input boxes (i already wrote onchange="updat1();"  but the function isn"t working and i dont know how to pass and hw to return correctly here it is ! :

```
function update1(x)
{


        var how_much = "#how_much[]";

        var item_price = "#item_price[]";

        var item_price_tax = "#item_price_tax[]";
        var item_price_tax3 = "item_price_tax[]";

        var item_price_total = "#item_price_total[]";
          var item_price_total3 = "item_price_total[]";


      var how_much2 =     document.getElementById("how_much[]").value;
           var item_price2 =   document.getElementById("item_price[]").value;
           var item_price_tax2 =  document.getElementById("item_price_tax[]").value;
         var item_price_total2 =  document.getElementById("item_price_total[]").value;


if((item_price_tax2==0)||(item_price_tax2=='')){

alert(2);

item_price_tax3.value = document.getElementById(item_price2).value * 1.17;
item_price_total3.value=document.getElementById(item_price2).value * 1.17 * how_much2;
item_price_tax[].value=document.getElementById(item_price2).value * 1.17 * how_much2;
item_price_total[].value=document.getElementById(item_price2).value * 1.17 * how_much2;
}

else{
item_price.value3 = document.getElementById(item_price).value * 83%;
item_price_total3.value=document.getElementById(item_price).value  * 83% * how_much;
}
}

</SCRIPT>
```

help needed thanks alot

Comment: Your control ids are all mixed up. You should use UNIQUE ids for jquery

Comment: even if i  do just name with number its dont work

this->
  $(wrapper).append('<div class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;"  align="center">שם המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="text" id="item_name'+x+'" name="item_name'+x+'" />&nbsp;כמות המוצר :<input type="number" id="how_much'+x+'" name="how_much'+x+'"  style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;"  onchange="update1('+x+');"  />&nbsp;עלות המוצר&nbsp; :<input type="number" id="item_price'+x+'"  style=" font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.2em; width: 95px;" name="item_price'+x+'" ....

also dont work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a couple things to fix here.

**First**, your `id` are not unique.

**Second**, you are using the long javascript `document.getElementById(xyz).value` instead of the shorter jQuery way `$(xyz).val()`.

**Third**, you are using the `x` incrementer everywhere. The incrementer was a good idea... But as you will see in the code I suggest below, I don't used it. It's only use is to be compared against `max_fields`.

**Fourth**, you are not using classe to style elements. Erverything is inline. This make the code harder to read and maintain.

**Last**, I placed your super long `append()` line on multiple lines... which makes the code way easier to read. *(I also translated hebrew! But this was for MY comprehension!)*

All these changes I made helped to understand your long apended line.
And all these things that where affecting readability probably are reasons why you got lost in your calculations.

**-----**
So... Here is what I suggest.
You can see it in action in **[this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/03oc3gmz/)**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields   = 99999; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper      = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button   = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 0; //initlal text box count

    //on add input button click
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var iwrapper = $( "<div class='input_fields_wrap'></div>" ).appendTo( wrapper );

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed

            //add input box
            $(iwrapper).append('<div class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;" align="center">');

            // Product name (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('שם המוצר&nbsp; :                <input type="text" class="item_name">');

            // Amount of product (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('&nbsp;כמות המוצר :          <input type="number" class="priceInput how_much">');

            // The cost of the product (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('&nbsp;עלות המוצר&nbsp; :        <input type="number" class="priceInput item_price">');

            // The cost after VAT (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('עלות אחרי מע&quot;מ&nbsp; : <input type="number" class="priceInput item_price_tax" disabled>');

            // Amount (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('סכום&nbsp; :                    <input type="number" class="totalInput item_price_total" disabled>');

            // Remove (hebrew translation)
            $(iwrapper).append('                                <a class="remove_field">הסר</a>');
            $(wrapper).append('</div>');

            x++;
        }
    });

    //user click on remove text
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })

    // Your "update1" function improved
    $(".input_fields_wrap").on("change",".how_much, .item_price",function(){

        var how_much = $(this).parent().children(".how_much").val();
        var item_price = $(this).parent().children(".item_price").val();

        if( how_much==0 || item_price==0 ){
            // rests displayed values to zero, user has not finished inputting values.
            $(this).siblings(".item_price_tax").val("");
            $(this).siblings(".totalInput").val("");
        }else{
            // Calculations
            item_price_VAT = item_price * 1.17;
            total = how_much * item_price_VAT;

            // Show calculated amounts
            $(this).siblings(".item_price_tax").val(item_price_VAT);
            $(this).siblings(".totalInput").val(total);
        }
    });
});
```

**NOTES:** I `disabled` the result inputs, since the user should not modify these (in my opinion). And here is the CSS I applied...

```
.priceInput{
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    width:95px;
}
.totalInput{
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.2em;
    width:125px;
}
.remove_field{        // This one replaces a unuseful href="#"
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:dodgerblue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**Bonus**
I wondered why you where using so many `[]`...
And came up with the idea that you could want to save these lines using arrays.

So here is how you will create arrays in your submit function:

```
// Prepare values into arrays...
var item_name_array=[];
var how_much_array=[];
var item_price_array=[];
var item_price_tax_array=[];
var item_price_total_array=[];

$(".item_name").each(function(i,val){
    item_name_array[i] = $(this).val();
    how_much_array[i] = $(this).sibling(".how_much").val();
    item_price_array[i] = $(this).sibling(".item_price").val();
    item_price_tax_array[i] = $(this).sibling(".item_price_tax").val();
    item_price_total_array[i] = $(this).sibling(".item_price_total").val();
});
```

Comment: it will not add row after rows deletion

Comment: Yes... This was the only use of `x` left... I just corrected my answer.

Comment: Yes... Ijust found the problem... Hold on

Comment: don't bother, I fixed it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112351/get-data-from-dynamic-form-into-javascript-and-returning-it-callculated/38113875#answer-38114128 =)

Comment: I found it.... It was because of the appending of a div... Which auto-closes. I had to make the append on one line againg. Fiddle is working now. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated my answer with your solution for this append bug... Which Is better. Sorry for that. Will you accept my answer anyway ?

Comment: wow thanks ! 

another question ?  

how do i use it now in php ?

or($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
   if(!empty($_POST["item_name"][$i]) || !empty($_POST["item_price"][$i])) {
    $itemValues++;
    
    echo'
    <td align="center">'.$_POST["item_price"][$i].'</td>
    <td align="center">'.$_POST["how_much"][$i].'</td>
    <td align="center">'.$_POST["item_name"][$i].'</td>


... this is what it was   this is why tryed to array it ! 
how you transfare it to php ?

thanks alot it helped alot

Comment: Right, good question. You have to use `JSON.stringify` on each array to send to PHP (on jquery side). And on PHP side, use `json_decode` to get it back to an array.

Answer (score 0):

**[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/9qh8r7zu/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var max_fields   = 99999; //maximum input boxes allowed
 var wrapper      = $("#wraper"); //Fields wrapper
 var add_button   = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

 var x = 0; //initlal text box count

 //on add input button click
 $(add_button).click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
    var iWrapper = $( "<div class='input_fields_wrap'></div>" ).appendTo( wrapper );    
    
  if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
   
   //add input box
   iWrapper.append('<div class="product-item float-clear" style="clear:both;" align="center">');
   
   // Product name (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('שם המוצר&nbsp; :    <input type="text" class="item_name">');
   
   // Amount of product (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('&nbsp;כמות המוצר :   <input type="number" class="priceInput how_much">');
   
   // The cost of the product (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('&nbsp;עלות המוצר&nbsp; :  <input type="number" class="priceInput item_price">');
   
   // The cost after VAT (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('עלות אחרי מע&quot;מ&nbsp; : <input type="number" class="priceInput item_price_tax" disabled>');
   
   // Amount (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('סכום&nbsp; :     <input type="number" class="totalInput item_price_total" disabled>');
   
   // Remove (hebrew translation)
   iWrapper.append('        <a class="remove_field">הסר</a>');
   iWrapper.append('</div>');
  }
 });

 //user click on remove text
 $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent('div').remove();
 })
 
 // Your "update1" function improved
 $(".input_fields_wrap").on("change",".how_much, .item_price",function(){
  
  var how_much = $(this).parent().children(".how_much").val();
  var item_price = $(this).parent().children(".item_price").val();
  
  if( how_much==0 || item_price==0 ){
   // rests displayed values to zero, user has not finished inputting values.
   $(this).siblings(".item_price_tax").val("");
   $(this).siblings(".totalInput").val("");
  }else{
   // Calculations
   item_price_VAT = item_price * 1.17;
   total = how_much * item_price_VAT;
   
   // Show calculated amounts
   $(this).siblings(".item_price_tax").val(item_price_VAT);
   $(this).siblings(".totalInput").val(total);
  }
 });
});
```

```css
.priceInput{
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 width:95px;
}
.totalInput{
 font-size:12px;
 line-height:1.2em;
 width:125px;
}
.remove_field{
 text-decoration:underline;
 color:dodgerblue;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_field_button">Add a row</button><br>
<br>
<div id="wraper">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes... ;) That was the problem. Nice way to fix it ;)